# Getting exception in timer picker dialog in api 9 in android

Tags: android

I am using custom timer picker dialogue in my app. It is working fine API version 11 or higher but getting exception in API version 9 or 10.

Can anyone help me?

**My code:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr">

    <!-- hour -->
    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/hour"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        />

    <!-- minute -->
    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/minute"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dip"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        />

    <!-- seconds -->
    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/seconds"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dip"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- AM / PM -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/amPm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dip"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dip"
    android:paddingStart="20dip"
    android:paddingEnd="20dip"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
    android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light_nodisable"
    />
```

**Exception:**

```html
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2179)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2535)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9129)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:618)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:123)
at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3826)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:969)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:727)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2174)
... 11 more
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.example.customtimepicker.TimePicker
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:601)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:654)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:439)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:351)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:307)
at com.example.customtimepicker.MyTimePickerDialog.<init>(MyTimePickerDialog.java:100)
at com.example.customtimepicker.MyTimePickerDialog.<init>(MyTimePickerDialog.java:67)
at com.example.customtimepicker.MainActivity.timePicker(MainActivity.java:24)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:536)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.customtimepicker.TimePicker$3
at com.example.customtimepicker.TimePicker.<init>(TimePicker.java:96)
at com.example.customtimepicker.TimePicker.<init>(TimePicker.java:82)
... 25 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Number Picker API is Added in API level 11, so you can not use it in xml file directly.

You have to create custom number picker to support API level 9. Please find link as below for custom number picker.

https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker

Comment: I have implemented same code for time picker but i'm getting excpetion.